# Fast calculation of distances to each cluster center for an entire dataset

Tags: python, performance, numpy, cluster-analysis, k-means

In a data clustering problem I have two numpy arrays, X and C, where X corresponds to observations and C corresponds to the centers of the clusters that can be formed with the data in X. Both of them have the same amount of columns (features) but C usually has way less rows than X. I'm trying to find a fast way of calculating the minimum squared distance between each observation in X and all the centers in C. In simple python this can be written as

```
D2 = np.array([min([np.inner(c-x,c-x) for c in C]) for x in X])
```

which is rather slow, so I mannaged to improve the speed by doin

```
D2 = np.array([min(np.sum((C-x)**2, axis=1)) for x in X])
```

instead, but I'm not yet satisfied with the execution time, and since a for loop still remains, I believe there is hope. Does anyone have an idea on how to further reduce the excecution time of this?

For the curious, I'm using this to generate seeds for K-Means through the K-Means++ algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest you'll get with the numpy/scipy stack is a specialized function just for this purpose [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html).

> `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(XA, XB, metric='euclidean', p=2, ...)`
>
> Computes distance between each pair of the two collections of inputs.

It's also worth noting that scipy provides kmeans clustering as well.

[`scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans.html#scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans)

Comment: Just what I needed. As for the K-Means algorithm, I'm actually using that implementations, K-Means++ is just a way of selecting seeds for it that produces better results than just randomly selecting them from the observations. Cheers!